# How do you daemonize a Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I have a small application written in Python using Flask. Right now I'm running it under nohup, but I'd like to daemonize it. What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[There are several ways to deploy a Flask project](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/). Deploying with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org) might be the easiest, install gunicorn and then:

```
gunicorn project:app --daemon
```

Although you probably want to use supervisor or something of that nature to monitor gunicorn (at the very least use `--pid` so you can reload/stop gunicorn easily).

Answer (score 7):

I an running centos with systemd working for all my other services. 
So I used the same for my flask app

Create a script sh with all my Flask settings

```
#!/bin/bash
# flask settings
export FLASK_APP=/some_path/my_flask_app.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=0

flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

Make this script as executable

> chmod +x path/of/my/script.sh

Add a systemd service to call this script

> /etc/systemd/system/ 
>  vim flask.service

```
[Unit]
Description = flask python command to do useful stuff

[Service]
ExecStart = path/of/my/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

To finish, enable it at boot

> systemctl enable flask.service

More info about systemd: https://www.tecmint.com/create-new-service-units-in-systemd/

Answer (score 2):

If you have supervisor installed already, I think gunicorn would be a little redundant. The following is a flask.ini file that can be dropped in /etc/supervisord.d/ (then "supervisorctl reload" to reload the config and start the process).

```
command=/opt/flask/env0/bin/python /opt/flask/developer/FlaskWebServer.py
directory=/opt/flask
redirect_stderr=true
startsecs=5
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/opt/flask/flask.stdout.log
```

Comment: Note that with this setup you are running the Flask built-in server, which doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to supervise it and keep it persistent across reboots, you could use [immortal](https://immortal.run)

You could call it like this:

immortal -l /var/log/your-app gunicorn project:app

Or via [run.yml](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/), for example:

```
cmd: gunicorn project:app
cwd: /path/of/project
env:
    DEBUG: 1
    ENVIRONMENT: production
 log:
    file: /var/log/app.log
    age: 86400 # seconds
    num: 7     # int
    size: 1    # MegaBytes
    timestamp: true # will add timesamp to log
 stderr:
    file: /var/log/app-error.log
    age: 86400 # seconds
    num: 7     # int
    size: 1    # MegaBytes
    timestamp: true # will add timesamp to log
 user: www
```

More about immortal: https://immortal.run/about/