# How to restart flask server?

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I am using Flask to create a web service. I hope to restart it like every 30 minutes. Is that possible to do that and how can it be realized?

Meanwhile, I tried to use subprocess (popen) to start the flask web service, terminate it and start it again, but the server could not be shut down unless the whole program, where I call subprocess, is also down.

I would very appreciate if you could share your knowledge and experience regarding to this issue.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Why do you want to restart it every 30 minutes? You could add a cronjob to handle this, but it sounds like you're doing something you don't need to do.

Comment: Some useful info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337119/how-do-you-daemonize-a-flask-application

Comment: I am using the web service to call an API where the login info seems to be expired in 30 minutes. After I manually shut the web service down and start it again, it works well as I want. It seems like cronjob is a promising solution, I will try it out.

Comment: Finally, I managed to use Popen to have flask as a subprocess, terminate it and restart it without any problem. The trick part is how to kill the flask cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flask web server is not supposed to serve production traffic.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/) You should consider using some other service on top of WSGI protocol, such as [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [apache mod_wsgi](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/).